# Cloudwatch metric: setting alarm for various times of day

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am setting most of my custom metrics to cloud watch. Most of the metrics if you see for the whole day it follow a sine wave. If I set an alarm to trigger if threshold goes below a certain value, the same threshold applicable during off peak hour.

from what I can see there is only one threshold I can set. Any suggestions how to sent is up more intelligently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can AWS CloudWatch alarms be paused/disabled during specific hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737359/can-aws-cloudwatch-alarms-be-paused-disabled-during-specific-hours)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not a static threshold alarm - but rather an alarm that uses a prediction model - look at the [CloudWatch Anomaly detection documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Anomaly_Detection.html)

These work very well with sine wave metrics from my own experience (like requests/traffic graphs that follow daily trends).

Alternatively, you can also use the metric math function RATE() that calculates the rate of change per second - and create an alarm on that (see [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html))

> Returns the rate of change of the metric, per second. This is
> calculated as the difference between the latest data point value and
> the previous data point value, divided by the time difference in
> seconds between the two values.

Description on how to create alarms on metric math can be found in their documentation as well: [Creating a CloudWatch alarm based on a metric math expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html)